# nodejs module unit test method gets called in private class

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to unit test that a method gets called in my module. The class and method are private and not exposed using `module.exports`. The modules I'm using for the tests are: `mocha`, `rewire`, `assert`, `sinon.spy`. The call I want to test is my error method, this currently throws an error, but might change later - so I don't want to test that an error is thrown, just test that `class.error()` gets called. Not sure how to procede and have tried numerous tuts online.

The class is (currently accessed in tests using `rewire`):

```
var MyClass = function MyClass(o){

    var self = this

    if(!o || typeof o !== 'object')
        self.error('No configuration passed to MyClass')
}

MyClass.prototype.error = function(msg){

    throw Error(msg)
}
```

My test currently, which is not working:

```
it('Constructs MyClass', function(done){

    //check constructs normally (this passes and works)
    var actual = obj.__get__("MyClass.config")
    assert.deepEqual(actual, config)

    /**
     * check calls error method
     */
    //stub class.error ?
    //construct class without config
    //check if class.error is called

    done()
})
```

In pseudo code, what I'm hoping to do is:

```
var stub = stub(MyClass)
    ->do('construct', null) //no config passed
    ->didCall('error') //check error method is called
```

This may be a duplicate of: [Mocking modules in Node.js for unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790505/mocking-modules-in-node-js-for-unit-testing)
But it is throwing an error me: `Object #<Object> has no method 'expect'`

Answer (score 0):

To solve it I imported the private class constructor using `rewire`, then I overrode the error method, setting it as a `sinon.spy`. I construct the class, then check if the spy was called:

```
//check calls error method if no config passed
var obj = rewire('./path/to/my/module')
    , MyClass = obj.__get__("MyClass")
    , spy = sinon.spy()

MyClass.prototype.error = spy
var foo = new MyClass()
assert.equal(spy.called, true)
done()
```